# How to navigate to another file through combo box?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox

I have created a lesson book using flash where every unit has many chapters. Their is a combo box to navigate in between the chapter. Those chapters are placed into individual frame. Now, if each chapter is a different .swf file (or HTML flash file if the publish preview is HTML), how can i access them through combo box? here is my code for combo box to navigate in between frame:

```
stop();

combobox.addItem( {label: "Chapter 1" } );
combobox.addItem( {label: "Chapter 2" } );
combobox.addItem( {label: "Chapter 3" } );


combobox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeFrame);

function changeFrame (event:Event):void{

    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 1")
    gotoAndStop ("chap1");
    else if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 2")
    gotoAndStop ("chap2");
    else if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 3")
    gotoAndStop ("chap3");
}
```

any help please? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that will load a swf, and display it on the screen.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

function loadSwf(swfURL:String):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(swfURL);                                           
}

function onComplete(e:Event)
{
    var swf:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    swf.addChild(e.currentTarget.content);
    addChild(swf);
}
```

Then call the function using the change event

```
function changeFrame (event:Event):void
{
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 1")
    loadSwf("chap1.swf");
    else if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 2")
    loadSwf("chap2.swf");
    else if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Chapter 3")
    loadSwf("chap3.swf");
}
```

You will then need to add in an if statement or something to check whether you need to remove a chapter that has already been loaded.

Comment: sorry for late reply, and thanks a lot for your answer. its working nicely!

Comment: well, if one swf file loaded, then its overlapping the previous one. how can i handle it? another issue is, when **chapter 2** selected, what can make combo box to display its **Chapter 2**? (normally if i add item same sequence like **chapter 1**, combo will show chapter 1 although **chapter 2** is selected.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of gotoAndStop, you want to do something like:

```
ExternalInterface.call('yourJavascriptFunction', combobox.selectedItem.label);
```

then, in Javascript, something like:

```
function yourJavascriptFunction(chapterName) {
  //set source of frame here
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help although it seems a bit complected to me(as i'm newbie in flash). but i voted up!:)